# Is $\sqrt{x}$ a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

if a function all have exactly one output per input, then how come $f(x)= \sqrt{x}$ is a function? assuming $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. When $f(-1)$ it outputs a complex number and is not part of the codomain, this is really confusing me.

My second confusion is f$(x)=1/x$, call it $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$. When $x = 0$,  it doesn't output a something in the co-domain since $1/0$ is undefined. So it must not be a function? Or is it I don't know. Pardon my English thank you.

Comment: A function is not just a formula; the domain and codomain are part of the definition of any function. E.g., $1/x$ is not a function on the reals, but it is a function on the nonzero reals.

Comment: It is rather confusing that $\mathbb R->\mathbb R$ is not allowed if the function is not defined for all real numbers. The domain is the set of non-negative real numbers , OK. But in the theory of turing machines it is common that a function over the naturals might be undefined for some (or all) natural numbers.

Comment: For $\sqrt x$  ,if your codomain is R then your domain should be$x>0$.

Comment: But to answer your question : For non-negative real numbers $x$ , there is a clear convention what $\sqrt{x}$ is, hence with the domain of the non-negative real numbers, $\sqrt{x}$ is a function. For negative $x$, there is no convention which complex (non-real) number we should choose.

Comment: For $\frac{1}{x}$, you can choose $\mathbb R$\{$0$} to get a function. For $x=0$, it is not defined.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer, my conclusion is I can just play with the domain.

Comment: If you searched "is sqrt a function", you'd find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53410/is-sqrtx-a-function-does-it-matter-if-a-domain-is-given). and if you searched "is 1/x a function", you'd find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912360/is-frac1x-a-function).

Comment: @SecretYesNo: Please don't vandalize questions (including your own!), especially after people have taken time to answer them.

Answer (score 4):

When we define any function $f: A \rightarrow B$, its domain $A$ must be carefully chosen so that $f(x)$ is a unique, well-defined, output for each input variable $x$ in the domain $A$.

If we take $f(x) = + \sqrt{x}$, then it is a well-defined function over the non-negative real number system, *i.e.* if we take its domain as

$A = \{ x \in \mathbf{R} : x \geq 0 \}$.

Similarly, if we take $g(x) = {1 \over x}$, then $g$ is well-defined except at the point $x = 0$.

Hence, $g(x)$ is a well-defined function over
$\mathbf{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} $, *i.e.*

Domain(g) = $\{ x \in \mathbf{R} : x \neq 0 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing there is that you **don't** have $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. Instead we usually either define it as a function $f:\mathbb{R}^+_0\to\mathbb{R}$, or a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ depending on our purpose. As you say, if we want the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$, then we need the codomain to be $\mathbb{C}$.

For $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, a similar thing applies. It is **not** a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$, but it **is** a function with domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.